# The system cannot infer the transport information from the vfs:sftp://user:password@sftpserverhost/in URL

Tags: wso2-esb

I am using the following code in my proxy to connect ftp server to read file from.

```
<proxy name="SFTPVFSProxy" transports="vfs" startOnLoad="true" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
      <target>
          <inSequence>

<send/>
          </inSequence>
      </target>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">vfs:sftp://username:password@ftpserver-host/outbox</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:sftp://username:password@ftpserver-host/inbox</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:sftp://username:password@ftpserver-host/sent</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.txt</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
</proxy>
```

But I am getting below error when I ran the above. VFS transport is eanbled in axis2.xml and I can see vfs transport in wso2 esb 4.9.0 admin console.

The system cannot infer the transport information from the vfs:sftp://user:password@sftpserverhost/in URL

Answer (score 0):

SFTP uses SSH protocol to communicate with the server, so it always logs into the user's home directory and then it takes the path relative to the user's home directory.
You can add "sftpPathFromRoot" to WSO2 VFS transport URI as to get absolute path access as below.
   `<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">sftp://[ username[: password]@] hostname[: port][ absolute-path]?sftpPathFromRoot=true</parameter>`
Alternatively you can use symbolic link.You can find more details [here](http://kalpapathum.blogspot.com/2015/04/workaround-for-absolute-path-in-sftp.html).

Comment: I am trying this example in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0. Looks like I am able to connect using SFTP but it's alway moving the file to failure directory MoveAfterProcess=/opt/X, MoveAfterFailure=/opt/y. In my case proxy always pushing the file into failure folder and message in log file INFO -  [JSCH] Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed